How to import a custom function into a custom action in flutterflow?
In my flutterflow project, I have a custom action and want to use a custom function into it.
Im using the following line to import the function:
import '../functions/my_function.dart';

But i had a following error during compilation:
Target of URI doesn't exist: '../functions/my_function.dart'. Try creating the file referenced by the URI, or try using a URI for a file that does exist.

Ps. I have also tried using import 'package:my_project/custom_code/functions/my_function.dart' to import it.
